# how can i solve this aws codedeploy error

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

Hi guys when I am trying to deploy a simple java app through code deploy iam getting this error

The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path *\"appspec.yml\"*

the zip file in s3 has both ROOT.war and AppSpec.yml file in it.

I have been navigated through the root directory and the codedeploy agent actually deployed the appspec.yml and *ROOT.war* in the correct path (i guess). but Still it is saying no AppSpec file
[I have provided the imge of linux directory which has both the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4aB.png)

anybody can help me with this?

The revision was unpacked to directory

*\"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/46a2d0a8-6af5-4deb-8650-4018ada5cf39/d-W8LSLP0E1/deployment-archive\"*,

and the AppSpec file was expected but not found at path

*\"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/46a2d0a8-6af5-4deb-8650-4018ada5cf39/d-W8LSLP0E1/deployment-archive/appspec.yml\".*

Comment: So your code source is s3 right?

Comment: Finally i figured out the problem, its the name of the appspec file, it needs appspec.yml but iam giving AppSpec.yml file ‍♂️.

finally the app deployed just now.
thankyou @sahith plika for responce.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out the problem, its the name of the appspec file, it needs appspec.yml but iam giving AppSpec.yml file ‍♂️. finally the app deployed just now. thankyou @sahith plika for responce.